# How color picker and strike (both ) will stay after reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap colorpicker and strike, but when I reload page both are gone, I want both stays after reloading the page. I have   used   before 
 **localStorage.body = document.body.innerHTML;** but it works only for one (color picker or strike). how both will work?

```
<div class="  container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-sm-4    ">
                <button class=" btn  btn-danger picker ">chnage color</button>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-sm-8 show_color ">
                <span>clicka</span>
                <span>not-click</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Flat-HTML5-Palette-Color-Picker-For-jQuery-colorPick-js/colorPick.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".picker").colorPick({
                'initialColor': 'onColorSelected',
                'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
                'onColorSelected': function() {
                    console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color);
                    $('.show_color').css('backgroundColor', this.color);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var $curParent, Content;
            $(document).delegate("span", "click", function() {
                if ($(this).closest("s").length) {
                    Content = $(this).parent("s").html();
                    $curParent = $(this).closest("s");
                    $(Content).insertAfter($curParent);
                    $(this).closest("s").remove();
                } else {
                    $(this).wrapAll("<s />");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

full  code is   here -https://codepen.io/omar-faruk-the-scripter/pen/QWWdgRR

Answer (score 0):

Omar that can not work :) If you save "the whole HTML" (btw uncool) then you can for sure save the currently set background. But then you change dynamically the strike trough but you do not save or restore this in any way.
I used a bit plain javascript to show you how it works. Yes it looks long and "complicated" but is just longer cause you missed half of the job. Its working, so give it a try.

```
                                  <html>
                <head>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Flat-HTML5-Palette-Color-Picker-For-jQuery-colorPick-js/colorPick.css">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
                    <!--   complete  code -->
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="  container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class=" col-sm-4    ">
                                <button class=" btn btn-primary picker ">change clolor </button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bgcolor" class=" col-sm-8 show_color ">
                                <span id="clicker" onclick="checkme();">click</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Flat-HTML5-Palette-Color-Picker-For-jQuery-colorPick-js/colorPick.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        var setup = {};
                        // just to keep things together
                        //switch the clicker states
                        function checkme() {
                            console.log(setup.check);
                            if (setup.check === "true") {
                                setup.check = "false"
                            } else {
                                setup.check = "true";
                            }
                            restoreclicker(setup.check);
                            localStorage.setItem("check", setup.check);
                        }
                        // sets the hatml acc. clicker value
                        function restoreclicker(value) {
                            var clicker = document.getElementById("clicker");
                            if (value === "false") {
                                clicker.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
                                clicker.innerHTML = "not clicked";

                            } else {
                                clicker.style.textDecoration = "none";
                                clicker.innerHTML = "clicked";
                            }
                        }
                        //restore box background
                        function restorebg(bg) {
                            setup.bg=bg;
                            var box = document.getElementById("bgcolor");
                            box.style.backgroundColor = setup.bg;
                        }
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $(".picker").colorPick({
                                'initialColor': 'onColorSelected',
                                'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
                                'onColorSelected': function() {
                                    console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color);
                                    $('.show_color').css('backgroundColor', this.color);
                                    setup.bg = this.color;
                                    // store bg temprary
                                    localStorage.setItem("bg", setup.bg);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        //restore settings on page load
                        if (localStorage.check) {
                            setup.check = localStorage.check;
                            restoreclicker(setup.check);
                        } else {
                            setup.check = "false"
                            localStorage.setItem("check", "false");
                        }
                        if (localStorage.bg) {
                            setup.bg = localStorage.bg;
                            restorebg(setup.bg);
                        }
                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: You own me a beer ;)

Comment: You should also set the foreground color of the text. Black on black is not very useful. Eg white text on dark backgrounds and dark text on whiote backgrounds.

Comment: it  is  not working, check your code - https://codepen.io/omar-faruk-the-scripter/pen/xxxgoOK

Comment: Small bug in the restorebg function header its corrected in the answer:) try again

Comment: this code is fine and works perfectly. what will we do we want multiple div, and every div color will be different?   like   this - https://codepen.io/omar-faruk-the-scripter/pen/xxxgoOK

Comment: You mean what you will that i do... :D I do not know how many thousands of settings you has but the way is totally the same. I would make a array with all the settings i want to keep updated...  Then i would transform this array to a JSON string and write the whole JSON String to the local storage on load i would fetch this string, recreate the array and update the page accordingly. In the answer i will give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

The whole things stands and falls just with your data setup. For the single instance you got the working code. If you has more then one of this fields I would give first every of the whatever its good for own ids. At least for the background and the span.

```
             <div ID="bg_1" onclick="setid(1);"><span id="clk_1" onclick="checkme(1);></span>
             </div>
             <div ID="bg_2"onclick="setid(2);" ><span id="clk_2" onclick="checkme(2);></span>
             </div>
             <div ID="bg_3" onclick="setid(3);"><span id="clk_3" onclick="checkme(3);></span></div>
                 ... to be continued
```

In the JS part I would modify the setup variable

```
              CURRENTBG=0;
              setup=[];
              for (i=0;i<32;i++) { // i use 32 for demo purposes
                 var tmp=[];
                 tmp.id=i+"";//creates a string used only for debugging
                 tmp.bg="ffffff";//creates a string
                 tmp.clk="false";//creates a string
                 // push !
                 setup.push(tmp);
              }
```

Now we have created a nice ARRAY with objects which can be easy updated and we do that very simple by a id number IDNR to address the acc. ARRAY line.

The store procedures can now be simplified. They mututate from:

```
               //localStorage.setItem("check", setup.check);
               //localStorage.setItem("bg", setup.bg);
```

to a nice function

```
             function storeSetup(){
               var STORAGEJSON = JSON.stringify(setup);//take a peek in the console log....!!!
               localStorage.setItem("setup",STORAGEJSON);
             }
```

which will store in fact the whole thing in a rush :) (that is why I like to keep things together and store them in arrays), This are the parts which updates the bg and clicker:

```
                function restorebg(IDNR,bg) {

                        setup[IDNR].bg=bg;           // watch this carefully
                        var id="bg_"+ IDNR;          //and this, its the trick

                        var box = document.getElementById(id);
                        box.style.backgroundColor = bg;
                       storeSetup();
                }

                function restoreclicker(IDNR,value) {

                        var id="clk_"+ IDNR;
                        setup[IDNR].clk=value;

                        var clicker = document.getElementById(id);
                        if (value === "false") {
                            clicker.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
                            clicker.innerHTML = "not clicked";

                        } else {
                            clicker.style.textDecoration = "none";
                            clicker.innerHTML = "clicked";
                        }
                    storeSetup();
                }
```

The setters are nearly same just got a IDNR and the new variable names
So whenever those functions are called they will store the values in the setup array and store that thing.

```
                function setid(IDNR){
                      CURRENTBG=IDNR;
                }



                 $(document).ready(function() {
                        $(".picker").colorPick({
                            'initialColor': 'onColorSelected',
                            'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
                            'onColorSelected': function() {
                      console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color);
                                $('.show_color').css('backgroundColor', this.color);
```

I do not know how you want to address a single colorbox to the different boxes. That's up to you - input field, click event etc. i use the setid function onclick which has done already the job and CURRENTBG has now the needed id

```
                             IDNR=CURRENTBG; //If you click on a background the
                                             //  CURRENTBG is updated

                             setup[IDNR].bg = this.color; //<<<<<<<< IDNR !!!
                             storeSetup();  // store whole setup
                            }
                        });
                    });



                    function checkme(IDNR) {

                        if (setup.check === "true") {
                             setup[IDNR].clk = "false"
                        } else {
                             setup[IDNR].clk = "true";
                        }
                        restoreclicker( IDNR,setup[IDNR].clk);
                        storeSetup();       // store whole setup
                    }
```

At Pageload on end of the script we do just exactly the opposite of storage

```
          var STORAGEJSON = localStorage.setup;
          var setup = JSON.parse(STORAGEJSON);
```

Now we got the values and have to update the web page:

```
               if (localStorage.setup) {
                      for (i=0;i<setup.length;i++) {
                        restorebg(IDNR,setup[i].bg);
                        restoreclicker(i,setup[i].clk);
                      }
               } else {
                    storeSetup();
               }
```

That's it! It's untested and up to you.